# SELECT SQL RETURNING NULL

Tags: mysql, date, select, max

I'm having trouble performing a select that returns me the last data added in the database by its date.

```
SELECT * FROM 
WHERE Prize 
WHERE dataPremio = (SELECT MAX (dataPremio) FROM Prize) 
    AND idLoteria =?
    AND idHerary = ?;
```

This command returns only the data that was entered today. If I didn't insert some data today, I'd like to returns from yesterday. But it's returning null. 
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using

```
SELECT * FROM Premio WHERE idLoteria=? AND idHorario=? ORDER BY dataPremio DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: Yeah, telling SQL which table to use is kinda an important point.